# Joomla 3 backend log in issue

Tags: joomla, migration, admin, joomla3.0

I built my site on my local machine on MAMP and I migrated the finished site to my remote server. I used Akeeba Backup and Kickstart and installed before making the final back up and then setting it up on the remote server.

However after doing so, I am no longer able to login to my admin. The passwords have not changed and the only thing I get is a yellow pop up message above the login box that says "Warning".

I reset my passwords several times but no success. The site works without a hitch so I don't think something went wrong on the migration but that wouldn't explain why I no longer can't log into my local instance.

I am a little perplexed. I am not sure if there is a bug with Akeeba Kickstart 3.9.

Comment: Is there by any chance a difference in PHP versions on your localhost and live server?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your remote server has the newer PHP version. The reason is that new PHP version generates the MD5 in a different way.

I also had the same issue once ... please try the following steps...

in you DB's Joomla user table

1. Backup the password'hash of your desired user.
2. Now go to [this](http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/) site and get the new MD5 hash of your password.
3. INSERT the new MD5 hash into DB.
4. Now try logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue even though my local MAMP was using PHP 5.3 and my remote server PHP 5.6 the actual problem was that for some reason the Joomla User plug in was disabled during the migration which caused me not being able to log in.

I went into my DB and set the flag from '0' to '1' and it resolved the issue. I am not sure how the parameter was changed but it was the culprit.